# how to hide a vertical scroll bar when I add options to the select element?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I use ajax to build a drop-down list. First time I click the drop-down list, it shows the list with a vertical scroll bar. The second time I click the drop-down list, the scroll bar disappeared. How to hide the scroll bar in the first time?

[image]

The following lines are a snippet code:

```
<select class="w3-select w3-border" name="building" id="building"  onclick="loadBuildingOptionsCall(this)" onchange="">
<option value="" disabled selected>select building</option>
</select>

function loadBuildingOptionsCall(obj){
 loadOptionsRequest('/loadBuildingOptions', loadBuildingOptions);}

function loadOptionsRequest(url, cFunction) {
              var xhttp;
              xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  cFunction(this);
                }
              };
              xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
              xhttp.send();
            }

    function loadBuildingOptions(xhttp) {
var obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
var elm=document.getElementById("building");
var optionCount=0;

for(var i=0;i<elm.childNodes.length;i++){
    if(elm.childNodes[i].nodeName=='OPTION') optionCount++;
}
if(optionCount==1){
    for (var key in obj) 
    {
        document.getElementById("building").innerHTML+="<option value='2'>"+key+"</option>";
    }
}}
```

Comment: overflow: hidden?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It still has the same problem.

Comment: I think this maybe your CSS cause, have you ever remove all style for your select and options and try again?

Comment: its come from your front css

Comment: just try to after change your Japaneses font.